# How to access other class members in C#

Tags: c#

New question and comments:

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.  I actually called SetFreq() from a 2nd thread.  I need two threads.  They both are running independent tasks.  The 2nd thread shares data for the main thread thru the Lru_Channel_Details class.  I'm having difficulty understanding how to access the ChFreq data member from the Lru_SetChanFreq class in the 2nd thread.  I updated the code below.  I hope it explains what I'm trying to do.  Sorry if not,  I am happy to clarify.

Thank you all again for recommendations.

Original question:

Forgive me, I'm new to C# and object-oriented programming.  I'm having difficulty accessing other class members. I've created other class objects to access their member fields. The code compiles but I don't get any results back when I display them. 
I'm unsuccessful to find an answer to my question. Can someone please show me what I have overlooked?  Below is a snippet of code illustrating my problem.

Thank you again for any recommendations you can give.

```
    // this class I want to use the value of ChFreq from the Lru_SetChanFreq class to do some stuff for the Lru_operation class in the main thread to use
public class Lru_Channel_Details
{
    public void actualFreq()
    {
        Lru_operation LruOp2 = new Lru_operation(); // create main operations class object to access ChFreq     
        Lru_SetChanFreq LruSetChFreq1 = new Lru_SetChanFreq();  // (optional): create other class object to access ChFreq

        Console.WriteLine("LruOp2.SetChanFreq.ChFreq = {0}", LruOp2.SetChanFreq.ChFreq);  // fails to display the ChFreq value
        Console.WriteLine("LruSetChFreq1.ChFreq = {0}", LruSetChFreq1.ChFreq);      // (optional:) also fails to display the value
    }
}

// in this class, I have set the values of ChFreq to 405.0.  the call to do this came from the Lru_Listen class which runs in a 2ndary thread.
// this class then calls the actualFreq() from Lru_Channel_Details class.  The Lru_Channel_Details class is also accessed from the Lru_operation class,  
// which is running in the main thread. 
public class Lru_SetChanFreq
{
    private string chFreq;

    public string ChFreq
    {
        get { return chFreq; }
        set { chFreq = value; }
    }


    public void SetFreq()
    {
        Lru_operation LruOp1 = new Lru_operation();  // this object accesses multiple other classes 

        LruOp1.SetChanFreq.ChFreq = "405.0";    // assign this value using main operations class object

        LruOp1.ChanDet.actualFreq();    // calls another class method to use ChFreq

        // does stuff with LruOp1 to access other class methods (not shown)
    }
}


// this is where the program begins.  I'm running 2 threads concurrently and I need to share data between them.
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{   
    // starts a 2ndary thread to do stuff while the main thread is working.  
    Lru_Listen LruListen1 = new Lru_Listen();
    Thread LruListenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LruListen1.ListenForAag));
    LruListenThread.Start();

    while(!LruListenThread.IsAlive);
    Thread.Sleep(1);

    Lru_operation LruOpX = new Lru_operation();         // create object to access Lru operation method
    LruOpX.LruOperation();



// this class is my main operations class.  it is running in the main thread.  the below objects are used to access other 
// class members.  it's main purpose is to take data from the Lru_Channel_Details class do some stuff on it and pass it to 
// another class.  it must be running in it's own thread. 
public class Lru_operation
{
    // this object is only used in other classes to access its class members.  it's not used in the main operations class
    public Lru_SetChanFreq SetChanFreq = new Lru_SetChanFreq();

    // this object is used in the main operations class to call methods from its class   
    public Lru_Channel_Details ChanDet = new Lru_Channel_Details();

    // does stuff with the above class objects' methods

}


// this class is running in a 2nd thread concurrently with the main thread.  it needs to share other class data with the main thread. 
// it's main purpose is to do some stuff to get data then call the SetFreq() from the Lru_SetChanFreq class 
public class Lru_Listen
{
    public void LruShowRequestData()
    {
        // do some other stuff      

        Lru_operation LruOp3 = new Lru_operation(); // create object to access set channel frequency method
        LruOp3.SetChanFreq.SetFreq();           // here is where SetFreq() from the Lru_SetChanFreq class is called
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never actually calling the SetFreq() method, so you'll never have any values in there.  Try setting it in the constructor:

```
public Lru_SetChanFreq()
{
    this.SetFreq();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  I tried your suggestion.  It created a stackoverflow exception error.  That's likely due to my Lru_operation class objects I create to access the data members.  Would you mind reading my above new question and comments to Grant?  I thought I could access other class members by creating an object to access them. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You never set the value of `ChFreq` so it is just its default value, an empty string.

```
Lru_SetChanFreq LruSetChFreq1 = new Lru_SetChanFreq();

// this 
LruSetChFreq1.ChFreq = "new value";
// or this
LruSetChFreq1.SetFreq()

Console.WriteLine("LruSetChFreq1.ChFreq = {0}", LruSetChFreq1.ChFreq);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion!  I didn't follow where you recommend that I insert the above code.  Is this withing the Lru_Chan_Details class  and inside the actualFreq() method? Would you mind reading my new question and comments as well as comments to the other two people?  Can I access another class data members without passing data thru the method argument list?  thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues I see:

- You're not calling `SetFreq` so the value is never set. You need to actually call `SetFreq` prior to your `Console.WriteLine` statements.
- And even if you were calling it, `SetFreq` creates a new instance of `Lru_operation` that is lost when the method is done running, instead of just assigning the value to the current one. Remove the three lines of code from `SetFreq` and replace them with: `chFreq = "405.0";`

Here's how you could modify your code to get the expected result. You just made a simple mistake.

```
public void actualFreq()
{
    Lru_operation LruOp2 = new Lru_operation();
    Lru_SetChanFreq LruSetChFreq1 = new Lru_SetChanFreq();

    LruOp2.SetChanFreq.SetFreq();
    LruSetChFreq1.SetFreq();

    Console.WriteLine("LruOp2.SetChanFreq.ChFreq = {0}", LruOp2.SetChanFreq.ChFreq);
    Console.WriteLine("LruSetChFreq1.ChFreq = {0}", LruSetChFreq1.ChFreq);
}
```

Comment: Hi Grant, Thanks for your help!  I tried your suggestions.  I must keep the LruOp1.ChanDet.actualFreq(); call (see my above new question and comments). It's my understanding that I can create an object to a class that I want to access its method.  Once i get into this method i.e. actualFreq(), I want to access the data member (ChFreq) from the class I came from.  I thought I could do that by creating an object LruSetChFreq1 and access ChFreq from that object.  I'm basically trying to bypass using the argument list to pass the members.  Can I do this? Which method ends Lru_operation instance?

Comment: Thanks again Grant.  I tried the fix.  It creates a stackoverflow exception error.  What's happening is that LruOp1.ChanDet.actualFreq();  is called from SetFreq().  Then LruSetChFreq1.SetFreq(); is called again from actualFreq() and I get into this endless loop.  See my updated code and question/comments above.  SetFreq() is running in a separate thread. it was initially called from the Lru_Listen class.  I test confirmed that ChFreq is assigned 405.0 in SetFreq().  This happened in the initial call from Lru_Listen class. Is there another way to access other class members?  Thank you again.